# Create multi column distinct index using mysql with rails migration

Tags: mysql, rails-migrations

Trying to execute this statement in a rails migration to generate a multi column unique constraint/index:

```
add_index :contributors, [:project_id, :user_id], :unique=>true
```

I've also tried providing an optional :name to the method, but still getting the failure. There are no existing keys in this table

```
Mysql::Error: Duplicate entry '5-9' for key 'distinct_user_and_project': CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `distinct_user_and_project` ON `contributors` (`project_id`, `user_id`)
```

How do I create this short of using execute and straight sql? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its clearly in error (`Duplicate entry '5-9'`) that your data is not unique so You can't add such index there

Comment: <sheepishly> uh, yeah...;-) Thanks; hadn't even considered that and sure enough, that was it.